# Failed to start zabbix3.0 in centos7

Tags: zabbix

I met a issue when I install zabbix3.0 by packages on centos7.
When I done on mysql , php , apache and configuration in zabbix.conf.
I run `systemctl start zabbix-server.service`.It didn't work!and show :
`Job for zabbix-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status zabbix-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`Then , my colleague told me to install `trousers` and `gnutls`,and then ,zabbix-server worked.What is the use of these two software?If they are necessary,Why not put them in the package of zabbix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you didn't install those packages, but upgraded them. They are linked in through the Jabber/XMPP support.

This was a bug in RedHat packages that took some time to resolve, see this bugreport : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1071171

And this is the Zabbix issue tracking the same problem : https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7790

Answer (score 1):

You won't start Zabbix Server 3.0 on CentOS 7 because you don't have "Disabled" SELinux.
You can disabled SELinux right here: `/etc/selinux/config`.
After that, you must reboot your server with `reboot` or `shutdown -r now`.
After reboot, confirm that the `getenforce` command returns **Disabled**.